# Upload File from Android to Tomcat

Tags: java, upload, jersey

I'm trying to receive an upload from an android device in an Apache Tomcat webserver. The code for android seems correct however I'm having issues handling the data on server side.

This is the client:

```
public String uploadStorageFile(String appId, String pathToFile) {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    DataInputStream inputStream = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";

    String storageUrl = url + "/" + appId + "/storage";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
    String serverResponseMessage = null;
    try
    {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToFile) );

    URL url = new URL(storageUrl);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Allow Inputs & Outputs
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    // Enable POST method
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

    outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // Read file
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    // Responses from the server (code and message)
    int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

    fileInputStream.close();
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    //Exception handling
    }
    return serverResponseMessage;
}
```

And this is server side:

```
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response uploadStorageFile(@Context UriInfo ui, @Context HttpHeaders hh, @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("filename") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail){
    String uploadedFileLocation = fileDetail.getFileName();

    // save it
    writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

    String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}
private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        String uploadedFileLocation) {

        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    uploadedFileLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The issue I'm facing is that fileDetail is null and so is uploadedInputStream, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>The two file-related Objects in your `uploadStorageFile` method are actually bound to the same `FormDataParam` (i.e. - `file`).</strike>

Try changing your `FormDataContentDisposition` to the same param name as the `InputStream`.

EDIT: Sorry, I missed something else completely. The name of the form param you are sending is actually "uploadedFile", not `file` or `filename`. Change both of your `FormDataParam`'s to be bound to the param named `uploadedFile` and they should no longer be null.

Comment: Thank you, I missed it completely.